# Making a picture into a circle view using CSS only

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

The following code works

```
<div style="width:485px; height:485px; border-radius:50%; overflow:hidden;">
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Squared Avatar" />
</div>
```

But these codes won't,

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:50%; overflow:hidden;">
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Squared Avatar" />
</div>
```

I just wonder why width and height have to be **px** in order to achieve such effect, rather than **percentage**? I know using percentage is more flexible than using px.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldong/hwrukLgw/), if we resize the result pane, you can see the P1 resizes automatically as expected for using percentage, so the question is where is this **100%** from? I thought that 100% indicates the width and height of the picture rather than the frame.

=====Update: 12/26/2014======

Thank you guys, **@jmore009** has answered the question.

I forgot *div* inherits width and height from its parent div, so the 100% is from the **body** element, which resizes when browser resizes by default.
Here's my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldong/hwrukLgw/1/).

Comment: your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/u7wL57um/

Comment: You can simply remove height width of div and give display inline block. You can rather control height width from img.

`<div style="display: inline-block; border-radius:50%; overflow:hidden;">
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Squared Avatar" />
</div>`

Comment: even % also work, as the image u r using is less the container width, u were not able to get the exact output, try 2 use a bigger image, r else you need to set a fixed container width to get the desired output

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hwrukLgw/2/ set image `width:100%` and `height:auto` so that it adjusts accordingly the div will adjust as per the image `height`

Comment: apply "border-radius:300px;" and you'll get your DIV as circle..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

percentages work off of a parent. it's saying `100%` of something else or `50%` of something else, if you do not define a parent's `height` and/or `width` (the highest level parent being `body` and `html`) then you have nothing to work off of.